# how to set the child number in a table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, css-selectors

I can call childs manually this way

```
     $("tr>td:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(n+3)").addClass("ClassName");
```

How do pass this value lets say in javascript I have

```
   var index = 5;
    $("tr>td:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child("'+index+'")").addClass("ClassName");
```

tried this way it doesn't works. My scenario is we have to find the index of a specific column and pass that index value. How to fix the above code

Comment: You haven't concatenated the values properly, I'd suggest using the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method instead. `$("tr>td:nth-child(1) tr").eq(zeroBasedIndex)`

Comment: $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] td').eq(woIndex).css("background-color", "yellow");...this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("tr>td:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(" + index + ")").addClass("ClassName");
```

For completeness, I also like @undefined method better:

```
$("tr>td:nth-child(1) tr").eq(zeroBasedIndex)
```

No string formatting bugs this way :)

Comment: $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] td').eq(index).css("background-color", "yellow");..it not working this way

Comment: Well the selector should work, just tried it out in a very simple example, http://jsfiddle.net/Yv2Y6/, so there must be something else going on, you should try to build an example :)

Comment: Can i set the color based on the col name instead of index ?

Comment: You could do something like `var col = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] td').eq(index); col.css("background-color", col.attr('name'))`

Comment: this works fine, but here i have group by functionality in the grid when we set this, as index is changed its setting the color on different one

Comment: Yeah well that's a whole other problem unfortunately :/